# How to order by two IN variables

Tags: mysql

Is there a way, in mysql, to order by two columns that are read in via Procedure?

**Example:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sort_by_two

(IN p_sort_1 VARCHAR(255)

IN p_sort_2 VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN 

select *

from table1

ORDER BY p_sort_1, p_sort_2;

END
```

I tried doing this already, but when I enter my column names, I am told they do not exist.

Comment: did you find any of the efforts in the answers below useful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sort_by_two(IN p_sort_1 VARCHAR(255),IN p_sort_2 VARCHAR(255))

    BEGIN
                SET @query =    CONCAT('select empnumber,p_sort_1_fieldname,p_sort_2_fieldname from table_1 order by ' ,p_sort_1,',',p_sort_2);
                PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
                EXECUTE stmt;


    END


    To use this:
     call sort_by_two('p_sort_1_fieldname','p_sort_2_fieldname');
   it should work..
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a MySQL [Prepared Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html). They are typically put together with a [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). And they always use a User Variable with an `@` sign. And not a Local Variable from a DECLARE.

**Schema:**

```
drop table if exists table1;
create table table1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    col2 int not null,
    col3 int not null
);
insert table1 (col2,col3) values
(1,1),(41,3),(21,2),(41,1),(31,18),(1141,2);
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
drop procedure if exists sort_by_two;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sort_by_two
(   IN p_sort_1 VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_sort_2 VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    set @theSql=concat("select * from table1 ORDER BY ",p_sort_1,",", p_sort_2);
    PREPARE stmt1 from @theSql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Test:**

```
call sort_by_two('col2','id');
call sort_by_two('col3','col2');
```

Looks like the testing works out fine.